# MongoDB - eval Vs. db.eval

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, eval

I have a simple stored script in system.js collection called getAllNotes.

script code: `function (x) {  return db.notes.find(); }`

notes is a collection holding the data I wish to extract.

`eval('getAllNotes()')`  - works well and returns the data.

`db.eval('getAllNotes()')` - returns a JSON string with various configuration that has nothing to do 
with my collection See below. Any idea? anyone understands the difference between executing eval and db.eval?

```
 "_mongo" : {
               "slaveOk" : false,
               "host" : "EMBEDDED"
       },
       "_db" : {
               "_mongo" : {
                       "slaveOk" : false,
                       "host" : "EMBEDDED"
               },
               "_name" : "test"
       },
       "_collection" : {
               "_mongo" : {
                       "slaveOk" : false,
                       "host" : "EMBEDDED"
               },
               "_db" : {
                       "_mongo" : {
                               "slaveOk" : false,
                               "host" : "EMBEDDED"
                       },
                       "_name" : "test"
               },
               "_shortName" : "notes",
               "_fullName" : "test.notes"
       },
       "_ns" : "test.notes",
       "_query" : {

       },
       "_fields" : null,
       "_limit" : 0,
       "_skip" : 0,
       "_batchSize" : 0,
       "_options" : 0,
       "_cursor" : null,
       "_numReturned" : 0,
       "_special" : false
```

Answer (score -1):

`eval` takes a string of code that it executes.

`db.eval`, according to the [docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.eval/), takes a function to call and a list of parameters to pass to that function. In other words, leave off the single quotes `'` here:

```
db.eval(getAllNotes())
```

As for the difference between the two, the docs also state it:

> The helper `db.eval()` in the mongo shell wraps the `eval` command. Therefore, the helper method shares the characteristics and behavior of the underlying command with one exception: `db.eval()` method does not support the `nolock` option.

Docs. Important stuff to learn things from before asking other people to do it for you.

Comment: I'd also add that there seems to be no reason to use `db.eval` here. Just run `db.notes.find()` from your client. Avoid `db.eval` whenever possible.